# What are the nested tables in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I am very new to Oracle and came across the concept of nested table. I want to understand that how are these tables stored and what are the use cases where we should use these tables.

Please share your thoughts or any useful online resources.

Comment: It as basically what you call in other languages as "Array" or "List"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle nested tables are a datatype which is used to store multi-valued attributes. You can think of it as a table getting stored in one of the columns of the parent table.

You can go through the below references for some better understanding of the syntax and the use cases.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_plsql_nested_table.htm

http://sql-plsql.blogspot.in/2007/05/oracle-plsql-nested-tables.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links.